# How to increment a MAX value without losing leading zero formatting

Tags: mysql

How can I increment, in a MySQL Query, a computed value such as a MAX value without losing the zero-fill format. My format is 00000 (varchar 5). My max value now is 00004. If I increment it I want 00005.

When I use this query:

```
        SELECT max( `num_dossier` ) +1 AS max
        FROM amep_dossier
```

I get a result of 5 and not 00005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would want to use ZEROFILL, http://hashmysql.org/wiki/Zerofill, set your field as INT and attribute it as (UNASSIGNED ZEROFILL) if you're using phpmyadmin.

```
CREATE TABLE amep_dossier (
   num_dossier INT(5) ZEROFILL,
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

Left-pad the computed number with zeros.

```
 SELECT LPAD( MAX(num_dossier) + 1, 5, '0') AS MAX
   FROM amep_dossier
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a MySQL bug report [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45875) explaining that using the MAX() function doesn't remove the zerofill flag from the column in the query results, but it fails to display the zeros.  Using LPAD() works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed it to a smallint(5) you could set it to `ZEROFILL` and it would auto-increment properly.